# Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 Grub issue on SSD Drive

Tags: 16.04, grub2, ssd

I have a server with SSD Drive. I try to install Ubuntu & bootloader in SSD Drive. All works fine during installation process. But after the server restarted, It can't boot to the OS.

What is there an issue with Grub bootloader installed on SSD Drive (NVM)?

Thanks.

Comment: no issue with Ubuntu Server to my knowledge; but the most common mistake is not telling the installer your boot device, or giving it a partition [/dev/sda3] & not device [/dev/sda].  the actual device is determined by your bios (& its settings) & mode used (legacy or uefi..)

Comment: I choose SSD Drive /dev/nvme0n1 for boot loader installation. This is the capture : https://ibb.co/g0PNZ5
After restarted, the server can't boot to the OS. I try to change Boot Mode to UEFI, but still problem.

Comment: I ran `df ` to check the exact drive name in Linux which was /dev/nvme0n1p1 in my case. Thanks @xme